# MetalLB on a host with multiple NIC

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, kubernetes, port-forwarding

I need help with some deeper networking stuff. Hopefully somebody can help me or at least push me to the right direction.

At the moment I have a two node bare metal (VPS) kubernetes cluster setup with microk8s.
Testingwith website deployments work great, routing based on ingress :-)

But now I want do deploy other services that are accessable by ports. I don't want to use NodePort, as the used ports will always be above 30000. Instead I want to use native ports, maybe 21 for a FTP server or something like that.

Deeper reading brought me to the metalLB extension (LoadBalancer for bare metal K8S). But unfortunatly, metalLb wants an IP **range** so I cannot use the different pubic IPs. My both machines have very different public IPs on eth0, accessable from the internet.

As a solution, I installed a second NIC on both machines (eth1) with a local network (192.168.1.10-192.168.1.11). Now I have a range of IPs I can provide to metalLB configuration.
On both hosts, I can ping the other machine on it's local address, so LAN is working.

But the Deployment (FTP for example) opened the port on the LAN address, maybe 192.168.1.11:21
That seems corrects as I provides these LAN-IPs to metalLB.

Now I want to access this service through the public IP. On each host, the public IPs *(let's call them **5.5.5.5** and **6.6.6.6** to make clear they are non-local)* are the default gateways, so there is NO default gateway for the LAN IPs (**192.168.1.x**)

I guess I need some DNAT / SNAT to route traffic, arriving at the public IP of a host the the second NIC (eth1) where a service is listening.

Finally I played a little bit with **IPTABLES** and tried to nat the traffic **between the interfaces**, but without luck.

I use latest ubuntu on both hosts, Port 21 is opened on the firewall on both hosts...
But finally I want to use multiple services with different ports. TCP and UDP aswell.

Is this solution possible at all?
Thank you for any ideas!